# InvocationTargetException when running a javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make own browser (exe file) using javaFX here is code:

```java
package com.ccs.flowybrowser;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Создание WebView
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        // Загрузка HTML-файла
        // Загрузка HTML-файла из папки resources
        String htmlFilePath = getClass().getResource("/index.html").toExternalForm();
        webEngine.load(htmlFilePath);


        // Создание сцены
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 800, 600);

        // Установка сцены на основную сцену
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // Заголовок окна
        primaryStage.setTitle("Мой Браузер");

        // Отображение окна
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When i launching code i have this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:893)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\Ukraine\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_372\jre\bin\jfxwebkit.dll
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1820)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1100)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.lambda$static$0(WebPage.java:133)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.<clinit>(WebPage.java:132)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:881)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:868)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:273)
    at com.ccs.flowybrowser.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.ccs.flowybrowser.HelloApplication
```

Error is in this line:

```
        WebView webView = new WebView();
```

I think that i need to add new dependency - org.openjfx.javafx-web:17.0.2, but it doesn't help me. Here is pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ccs</groupId>
    <artifactId>flowybrowser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>flowybrowser</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
                <version>17.0.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.ccs.flowybrowser/com.ccs.flowybrowser.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my project structure:
`

- src

  - main

    - java

      - com

        - ccs

          - flowybrowser

            - HelloApplication.java
    - resources

      - index.html
        `

Comment: Hi add  `requires javafx.web;` to module-info